# Why there is no variable ' not defined' error if I could connect successfully in Python

Tags: python, mysql, try-catch

I wrote code to connect to MySQL, and if I connect successfully it works well like the following:

```
from mysql import connector

try:
    conn = connector.connect(host="localhost", database="world", user="root", password="rightPWD")
    print(conn.is_connected())

except connector.Error as err:
    print(err)
finally:
    conn.close()
```

But if I intentionally use the wrong password:

```
try:
    conn = connector.connect(host="localhost", database="world", user="root", password="wrongPWD")
    print(conn.is_connected())

except connector.Error as err:
    print(err)
finally:
    conn.close()
```

There I will get an error:

```
1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Nico/pycharm/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1483, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/Nico/pycharm/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/Nico/Documents/test/mideterm.py", line 10, in <module>
    conn.close()
NameError: name 'conn' is not defined
```

I know in Java a variable shouldn't be defined within a try{} and then use it in finally{}, but in Python, if I do so and connect successfully, there seems nothing goes wrong. but if I failed, the "NameError: name 'conn' is not defined" will jump out.

what is the mechanism behind it?

Answer (score 0):

It wil always enter finally so you must have an object defined prior

You could do

```
from mysql import connector
conn = None
try:
    conn = connector.connect(host="localhost", database="world", user="root", password="rightPWD")
    print(conn.is_connected())

except connector.Error as err:
    print(err)
finally:    
    if conn is not None:
        if conn.is_connected():
            conn.close()
```

Fir your question the complete try catch finally is a scope so everything defined on it exists till finally is concluded

Comment: I think my question is why there is no throwout if the database can be connected successfully when I didn't define conn outside the try{}

Comment: Ok I added that part